# The Class loading process when integrating Clojure, Spring and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, clojure

We used Spring MVC and clojure together to build WAR web apps and deploys the app using Tomcat. The controllers are implemented in clojure, with `gen-class` generating annotated class files to be scanned from Spring framework.

When I print the classpath by:

```
(seq (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader)))
```

I got only `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/bootstrap.jar` and `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar`. I was expecting the `webapp/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes` to be listed in the seq. Why?

The stacktrace when printing from the clojure part of code is as follows:

```
java.lang.Exception: at columbus.controller$_hello.invoke(controller.clj:17) 
at columbus.controller.TestController.hello(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) 
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, I wanted to load some property files in the classpath, or rather, under WEB-INF/classes. But with such ClassLoader, the file is not accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader` gives you the classloader used by the JVM and Tomcat. Each webapp is given its own classloader, when tomcat reloads the application it discards the current application classloader and creates a new one.

The system classloader is the parent of the application classloaders. When you look for something in a classloader, the classloader you start with delegates to its parents first, then if its parents can't find anything matching it tries to load it itself. But it does not look in child classloaders. So if you start from the system classloader you won't find anything specific to your web application there.

In your application code you can get some class loaded by your application (like your TestController) and call getResourceAsStream on it, and it will look for the file matching the path you give it under WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Brilliant! I've been stuck at the problem for days. The reason is that I mistaken System class loader for context class loader, so I always failed to load the resource. Now I can load the resource with java.io/resource with no problem

Comment: @Davyzhu: careful, context classloader is something else altogether, it provides a way for a class loaded by parent classloader to load resources available to a child classloader.